# Understanding output of ps -ef on linux

Tags: linux, process, administration, system-information

When I do ps -ef on my Linux box, I get:
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD

Please help me with meaning of C,TIME.
is the TIME , the actual cpu time allocated to the process?

Comment: Run `man ps` and type `/ C ` with the spaces around C to search for the answer.

Answer (score 8):

If you run `man ps` then type <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Shift+C</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, you should see this line.

```
   C     pcpu         cpu utilization
```

but that's under the `OBSOLETE SORT KEYS` header, so is not what we're looking for.

Press `n` to find the next match:

```
   c           C         processor utilization. Currently, this is the
                         integer value of the percent usage over the
                         lifetime of the process.
                         (see %cpu).
```

which sounds right.  For more details, we search for `%cpu` and find:

```
   %cpu        %CPU      cpu utilization of the process in "##.#" format.
                         Currently, it is the CPU time used divided by the
                         time the process has been running cputime/realtime
                         ratio), expressed as a percentage. ...
                         (alias pcpu).
```

And `TIME` has two matches, but only one that matches the `hh:mm:ss` format:

```
   cputime     TIME      cumulative CPU time, "[DD-]hh:mm:ss" format. (alias time).
```

---

Cumulative CPU time is the amount of time the processor spent running the process, i.e. actually using CPU cycles, not sleeping, waiting to run, or waiting for I/O.

It's determined by summing the `utime` and `stime` values that are described in the [proc(5) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc).

```
  utime %lu   Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode...
  stime %lu   Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel mode...
```

Comment: +1 for guiding easier browsing in `man ps`